# Draw svg Icons in Avalonia

Tags: .net, svg, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am facing some issues while rendering SVG icons in avalonia v11.0.6 using [FluentAvalonia](https://github.com/amwx/FluentAvalonia) v2.0.5 framework.

Example svg:

```
<svg width="25" height="24" viewBox="0 0 25 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M12.3101 16H16.3101M12.3101 16H5.31006C4.77963 16 4.27092 15.7893 3.89584 15.4142C3.52077 15.0391 3.31006 14.5304 3.31006 14V6C3.31006 5.46957 3.52077 4.96086 3.89584 4.58579C4.27092 4.21071 4.77963 4 5.31006 4H19.3101C19.8405 4 20.3492 4.21071 20.7243 4.58579C21.0993 4.96086 21.3101 5.46957 21.3101 6V8.24454M12.3101 16V20M12.3101 20H16.3101M12.3101 20H8.31006" stroke="#202020" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

Code usage:

```
xmlns:ui="using:FluentAvalonia.UI.Controls"   
 
<ui:FAPathIcon Data="M12.3101 16H16.3101M12.3101 16H5.31006C4.77963 16 4.27092 15.7893 3.89584 15.4142C3.52077 15.0391 3.31006 14.5304 3.31006 14V6C3.31006 5.46957 3.52077 4.96086 3.89584 4.58579C4.27092 4.21071 4.77963 4 5.31006 4H19.3101C19.8405 4 20.3492 4.21071 20.7243 4.58579C21.0993 4.96086 21.3101 5.46957 21.3101 6V8.24454M12.3101 16V20M12.3101 20H16.3101M12.3101 20H8.31006" />
```

Expected output:

[image]

Real output:

[image]

As I understand it, the problem is that I can't set the fill to "none" as a rendering rule, and I have no idea how to achieve that.

The question is how I can draw such or similar svg icons in avalonia.